# just installed 7.12 - but got stuck - how to access the backend and login

Tags: 7, installation

good day dear drupalers,

just installed 7.12 - but got stuck - how to access the backend. i have no glue.

see the page: http://www.boysday.org - i do not know how to proceed. how can i see the backend.

**btw.** i do not know the passwd. and the admin-login-name. 
and i do not know the link to the login page: 
i was in a hurry while i installled all.

see the result on http://www.boysday.org :

```
Page not found
The requested page "/" could not be found.
```

**question 1:** can the data (login name and passwd) be accessed via the backend!? Can i obtain the data to access the backend of the freshly installed D 7.12 while i look at the backend of the site - with phpmyadmin.

**question 2:** if i have the data - where to go - which link should i follow to acess a login-screen?

look forward to hear from you

greetings

**btw:** there was a lot of noise during the installation - have a look at this folllowing data: - what do you say...!?

http://boysday.org/install.php?profile=standard&locale=en&op=start&id=1

```
Warning: opendir(modules/simpletest/tests/themes/test_theme) [function.opendir]: failed to open dir: Too many open files in file_scan_directory() (line 2034 of /home/vhost/WWW/boysday.org/includes/file.inc).
Warning: opendir(modules/field/modules/list/tests) [function.opendir]: failed to open dir: Too many open files in file_scan_directory() (line 2034 of /home/vhost/WWW/boysday.org/includes/file.inc).
Warning: opendir(modules/update/tests/themes/update_test_basetheme) [function.opendir]: failed to open dir: Too many open files in file_scan_directory() (line 2034 of /home/vhost/WWW/boysday.org/includes/file.inc).
Warning: opendir(modules/update/tests/themes/update_test_subtheme) [function.opendir]: failed to open dir: Too many open files in file_scan_directory() (line 2034 of /home/vhost/WWW/boysday.org/includes/file.inc).
Warning: opendir(modules/block/tests/themes/block_test_theme) [function.opendir]: failed to open dir: Too many open files in file_scan_directory() (line 2034 of /home/vhost/WWW/boysday.org/includes/file.inc).
Warning: opendir(modules/simpletest/tests/themes/test_theme) [function.opendir]: failed to open dir: Too many open files in file_scan_directory() (line 2034 of /home/vhost/WWW/boysday.org/includes/file.inc).
Warning: opendir(modules/field/modules/list/tests) [function.opendir]: failed to open dir: Too many open files in file_scan_directory() (line 2034 of /home/vhost/WWW/boysday.org/includes/file.inc).
Warning: opendir(modules/update/tests/themes/update_test_basetheme) [function.opendir]: failed to open dir: Too many open files in file_scan_directory() (line 2034 of /home/vhost/WWW/boysday.org/includes/file.inc).
Warning: opendir(modules/update/tests/themes/update_test_subtheme) [function.opendir]: failed to open dir: Too many open files in file_scan_directory() (line 2034 of /home/vhost/WWW/boysday.org/includes/file.inc).
Warning: opendir(modules/block/tests/themes/block_test_theme) [function.opendir]: failed to open dir: Too many open files in file_scan_directory() (line 2034 of /home/vhost/WWW/boysday.org/includes/file.inc).
```

what do you say...!? ,look forward to hear from you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to get the password from the database, but you *will* be able to get the email address for user 1 and then request a new password by email.

Have a look in the `users` table for the email address for the entry with a `uid` of 1. Then go to http://mysite.com/user/password, pop in that email address, and wait for instructions to be emailed to you.

After you've re-gained access to the site you can log back in again at any time by going to http://mysite.com/user. The admin backend will most likely be at http://mysite.com/admin, unless someone has changed it (this is unlikely).

The errors you got during install are because of a UNIX limit on the number of open files/file descriptors in the system. Take a look at [this article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-increase-the-maximum-number-of-open-files/) for some suggestions on how to increase that limit so you don't run into the same error again.

It might be that you need to raise this limit and then re-install the site again...I'm not sure if the errors you've received will have stopped the site from being installed properly or not.

Comment: hi there - thxalot - i will have a closer look at all your advices. AT the moment i am not at home - i cannot do alot here - but will do so later the day. Come back and report all my findings

Comment: See also: [Fatal error: Call to undefined function field_attach_load() in includes/entity.inc on line 321 during install](https://drupal.org/node/481758)